# Pre-loading string into search bar & searching from segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

Question is similar to this one: [Setting searchBar.text in view did load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465185/setting-searchbar-text-in-view-did-load)

I have my keyword from V1 passing to V2 without issues; I'm trying to set it as search bar text & search from previous segue.

String is called `searchText`.

I've tried

```
    self.searchBar.text = self.searchText;
```

in viewWillAppear & viewDidLoad of V2 but nothing is showing up in my search bar.

How can I get my searchText into the search bar and filtering my table after segue from V1 to V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the string is not empty before setting it as searchbar text?

The following code works perfectly for me.

```
@interface ViewController (){
    NSString *searchText;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    searchText = @"I love ice cream!";
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.searchBar.text = searchText;
}
```

This is a method how you can check if the string is empty:

```
self.searchBar.text = (searchText == nil || searchText == (id)[NSNull null] || searchText.length == 0) ? @"To bad, an empty string" : searchText;
```

Comment: Not empty but    `self.searchBar.text = searchText` doesn't seem to have any reaction.

Comment: Have you tried a breakpoint after setting the text? You can than inspect the value of "searchText" in the console (po self.searchText) or in the variables view.

Comment: Yeah, I see my value in the console. In viewWillAppear I have        `NSLog(@"%@", self.searchText);` right before
    `self.searchBar.text = self.searchText;`

Comment: Are you sure you have connected the UISearchbar outlet to the storyboard object?

Comment: Bingo! One problem though: the table is not filtering, but the search term is in the search bar.

Comment: Nice :) For the actual filtering you need to implement some logic, the UISearchBar is just a static object if you don't tell him what to do. The [UISearchBarDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate) describes what you can do with it.

Comment: Na, I mean, I already have filtering working fine - but this instance where it's inherited from view #1 setting the bar text doesn't automatically filter - like my predicate does.

Comment: Is there anyway to call searchBarSearchButtonClicked programmatically before and then endEditing after?!

Comment: hahah so I put `    self.searchDisplayController.active = YES;` in front and ` [self.searchBar endEditing:YES];` at the end!